# Having problems with extending generic classes

Tags: java, generics, compare, generic-programming

I am trying to create a generic class called "OrderedList", which uses an array of generic types to store a specific type using the types pre-defined sorting. I am having trouble with what should seem like a simple operation and I don't understand why. Here is my code.

```
    public OrderedList() {
        list = (T[]) new Object[100];
        size = 0;
    }

    public <T extends Comparable<T>> void add(T o) {
        if (size == list.length) resize();
        list[size] = o;

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            o.compareTo((T) list[i]);
        }
        size++;
    }

    private void resize() {
        int newSize = (int) (1.5 * (double) list.length);
        T[] newArray = (T[]) new Object[newSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            newArray[i] = list[i];
        }
        list = newArray;
    }
```

The error I am getting is with the second line in the add method, "list[size] = o". It is providing me with an error that says "Incompatible Types. Required: T. Found: T." Also, whenever I take the instantiation of `<T extends Comparable<T>>`, that error goes away but then I cannot compare the two objects that I am trying to sort within the generic array.

Can anyone help me? I really am confused with this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You need to put the `T extends Comparable<T>` in the **class** signature, not the **method** signature.

```
class OrderedList<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    T[] list;
    int size;

    public OrderedList() {
        list = (T[]) new Object[100];
        size = 0;
    }

    public void add(T o) {
        if (size == list.length) resize();
        list[size] = o;

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            o.compareTo((T) list[i]);
        }
        size++;
    }


    private void resize() {
        int newSize = (int) (1.5 * (double) list.length);
        T[] newArray = (T[]) new Object[newSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            newArray[i] = list[i];
        }
        list = newArray;
    }
}
```